# How to handle domain objects name changes in software?

Tags: architecture, refactoring

What is the best practice or pattern to handle situation when some name from the domain changes?

For example, let's say that I am developing a software for a car sale. So, I would have Car domain object, CarService, CarDTO, FetchCarRequest, SaveCarRequest, and so. Also, I'd have a bunch of localized strings where their key contains word car.

And, let's say that the boss, customer or product owner decide that "Car" is not a right word, and decide to change it to "Auto" or "Vehicle". Of course, he doesn't care about what is happening inside the software, the only thing he cares is that on the user interface we replace all cars with autos or vehicles.

Now, my question is, how to approach to this issue?

1. Should I just change localized strings, and remember/document that
   whenever anyone (boss, QAs, users in app reviews...) talks about
   vehicles, they think about the thing we call "Car" in our software?
2. Refactor every fckng place of our code where word "Car" is mentioned
3. Something completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I just change localized strings, and remember/document that
>   whenever anyone (boss, QAs, users in app reviews...) talks about
>   vehicles, they think about the thing we call "Car" in our software?

Yes. If any term in the UI changes, you definitely need to change all sentences, that touch it. If you need to do that often, you could construct an index. But if you need to do that often, something is wrong with your process.

> Refactor every fckng place of our code where word "Car" is mentioned

This is another thing. In DDD you use [Eloquent language](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UbiquitousLanguage.html) to describe bussiness logic of your application. You use this language when you talk to your teammate, analyst, project manager etc. You use it in the code. And if suddenly something happens, that forces you from now on to speak to all those people using different terms... Then why... you HAVE to refactor your code. Because otherwise you will have a mixtire of terms everywhere, confusing and bugs causing.

But again. If this situation arises too often in your process... Someone needs to think it over seriously.

Comment: It seems logical to me that nouns used in code should follow 100% nouns used in domain. But, you know how it works, it is business decision that Player becomes Customer, Car becomes Auto, or Visit becomes Interaction, or however someone decided to be, and it happens once in a while as business develops and/or pivots, and it seems painful sometimes to follow those changes, so I wanted to hear about other experiences and best practices. Thank you for your answer.